# ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism AMQPLAIN. For details see the broker logfile

Tags: python, django, celery, supervisord

I'm getting this error when I try to perform `celery -A draft1 beat` in my terminal.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/apps/beat.py", line 107, in start_scheduler
    service.start()
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 558, in start
    interval = self.scheduler.tick()
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 279, in tick
    self.apply_entry(entry, producer=self.producer)
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 44, in __get__
    value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 411, in producer
    return self.Producer(self._ensure_connected(), auto_declare=False)
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 395, in _ensure_connected
    _error_handler, self.app.conf.broker_connection_max_retries
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 405, in ensure_connection
    callback)
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 333, in retry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 261, in connect
    return self.connection
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 802, in connection
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 757, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 130, in establish_connection
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 288, in connect
    self.drain_events(timeout=self.connect_timeout)
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 471, in drain_events
    while not self.blocking_read(timeout):
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 477, in blocking_read
    return self.on_inbound_frame(frame)
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/method_framing.py", line 55, in on_frame
    callback(channel, method_sig, buf, None)
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 481, in on_inbound_method
    method_sig, payload, content,
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 128, in dispatch_method
    listener(*args)
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 603, in _on_close
    (class_id, method_id), ConnectionError)
amqp.exceptions.AccessRefused: (0, 0): (403) ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism AMQPLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.
```

I'm running celery on my remote Ubuntu django server.

Any idea what the problem is?

Here's my code:

settings

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'post_jobs': {
        'task': 'post.tasks.post_jobs',  # the same goes in the task name
        'schedule': crontab(minute=40),
    },
    'test_post': {
        'task': 'post.tasks.test_post',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=40),
    }
}
```

draft1/celery.py

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'draft1.settings')

app = Celery("draft1", broker=CELERY_BROKER_URL)
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

post/celery.py

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'draft1.settings')

app = Celery(broker=CELERY_BROKER_URL)
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

post/tasks.py

```
@app.task
def test_post():
    from .models import Post
    for i in Post.objects.all():
        if i.entered_category == "test":
            i.entered_category = "not_test"
            i.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

postr-celery.conf

```
[program:postr-celery]
command=/home/james/postr/env/bin/celery -A post worker --loglevel=INFO
directory=/home/james/postr
user=james
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/celery.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/celery.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 600

stopasgroup=true

; Set Celery priority higher than default (999)
; so, if rabbitmq is supervised, it will start first.
priority=1000
```

I'm not sure what sparked this error, my celery was working recently. Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 4):

There is a good chance that a software update of the SSL features caused the problem. I found my issue in the /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@host.log file.

In my case, I found the following, and to resolve I had to re-install my rabbitmq / celery.

/lib/erlang/lib/crypto-4.2/priv/lib/crypto: 'libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file

a test of rabbitmqctl list_users and add_users can help determine if your rabbitmqctl is installed correctly when you monitor the logs.